# How can I read a file in mt5 tester?

Tags: mql5

This code works when it does not run in the tester...
How can I load this file when running this code (an EA) in the tester.
The file is located under mql5/Files but that does not work when running this code in the tester.

```
int OnInit()
  {
//---

  
   file_handle=FileOpen(Csv,FILE_READ|FILE_CSV|FILE_SHARE_READ,',');
   if(file_handle==INVALID_HANDLE)
   {
   
     Alert("could not open file "+Csv," Error: ",GetLastError());
     return INIT_PARAMETERS_INCORRECT;
   }

   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
```

One solution is to copy the file into testing_agent_directory\MQL5\files... But this needs to be done repeatedly...(Based on the suggestion by PaulD) as the files gets deleted at the end of the simulation.
Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, work with files is strictly controlled in the MQL5 language. Files with which file operations are conducted using MQL5 means, cannot be outside the file sandbox.

[FileOpen(file_name, open_flags, delimiter, codepage)](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/files/fileopen)

According to the documentation, the file is opened in the folder of the client terminal in the subfolder MQL5\files (or testing_agent_directory\MQL5\files in case of testing).

You therefore need to change the location of your files to be opened when testing.

Comment: the files gets deleted if I copy it over there. It needs to be done before every simulation.

Comment: The file should not get deleted unless you are using the `FileDelete()` command somewhere in your code

Comment: Well, it is deleted, the program does not delete it.